# Cocos2d (iOS): scheduleOnce called in callback won't fire

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scheduler

I am scheduling a callback via *scheduleOnce* (Cocos 1.1b), and when the callback is executed and once all tasks were performed there, I try to reschedule the same callback again (just with a different delay). The reasoning is to achieve a varying delay between the callbacks.
However, while it is called properly the first time, the second scheduling will never fire it again. Stepping through the Cocos libs, it eventually adds a timer to the list, but it won't fire.
Any clue what I am doing wrong and need to do differently?

Edit: just saw this entry in the log on the second scheduling:

`CCScheduler#scheduleSelector. Selector already scheduled. Updating interval from: 0.00 to 0.00`

I tried now to unschedule all timers explicitly first, however it doesn't make a difference. I would anyway expect *scheduleOnce* to reset that timer on callback.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bug in Cocos2D, after all you're using the very latest beta version. So I won't divulge into that, you may want to report this through the official channels however (cocos2d forum, google code issues for cocos2d-iphone).

In the meantime you can simply do this:

```
-(id) init
{
  …
  [self scheduleSelector:@selector(repeat) interval:0];
}

-(void) repeat
{
  // simply schedule the selector again with a new interval
  [self scheduleSelector:@selector(repeat) interval:CCRANDOM_0_1()];
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to re-schedule the selector at a later time, you can unschedule it as follows within the repeat method (the _cmd is shorthand for the selector of the current method):

```
-(void) repeat
{
  [self unschedule:_cmd];
  // re-schedule repeat at a later time
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion already, but _scheduleOnce_ is basically implemented exactly like that (using a new extended signature, including a _repeat_ and _delay_ parameter), so the result is the same. I think there's a bug in the reschedule-code -- will report.